# Rotated QGraphicsRectItem moves randomly when dragged using mouse

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsrectitem

I have a movable QGraphicsRectItem which is rotated to 90 degrees and set to a scene. When I drag the item, it moves randomly and eventually disappear.

However, when I set the rotation to 0, the item moves flawlessly.

Here is my minimal reproducible example.

```
class main_window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.rect = Rectangle(100, 100, 100, 100)
        self.rect.setRotation(90)

        self.view = QGraphicsView(self)
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self.view)
        self.scene.addItem(self.rect)

        self.view.setSceneRect(0, 0, 500,500)
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)

        self.slider = QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.slider.setMinimum(0)
        self.slider.setMaximum(90)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.view)
        vbox.addWidget(self.slider)

        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.rotate)

    def rotate(self, value):
        self.angle = int(value)
        self.rect.setRotation(self.angle)

class Rectangle(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsScenePositionChanges, True)
        self.setPen(QPen(QBrush(QtGui.QColor('red')), 5))
        self.selected_edge = None
        self.first_pos = None
        self.click_rect = None

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.first_pos = event.pos()
 
        self.rect_shape = self.rect()
        self.click_rect = self.rect_shape
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        # Calculate how much the mouse has moved since the click.
        self.pos = event.pos()
        x_diff = self.pos.x() - self.first_pos.x()
        y_diff = self.pos.y() - self.first_pos.y()

        # Start with the rectangle as it was when clicked.
        self.rect_shape = QtCore.QRectF(self.click_rect)

        self.rect_shape.translate(x_diff, y_diff)

        self.setRect(self.rect_shape)
        self.setTransformOriginPoint(self.rect_shape.center())
```

(I included a slider at the bottom of the main window to conveniently rotate the item)

Why does this happen?

Comment: You're setting the `ItemIsMovable` flag, implementing the movement in the mouse events is useless: try commenting both those functions and you'll see.

Comment: Hi @musicamante, your solution worked wonderfully. However, if I comment the `ItemIsMovable` flag and keep on implementing the mouse events, the issue still persists. I found out that commenting `self.setTransformOriginPoint(self.rect_shape.center())` while still using the mouse events also resolved the issue. This means that `setTransformOriginPoint` makes the item move randomly when dragged. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: The fact is that you're still using a QGraphicsRectItem that is positioned at a certain point, but has a rectangle with different coordinates (remember, QGraphics shape items have their shape positioned *relative* to their position). This creates a very complex issue with the transformation: the mouse position (which is based on *integer* values) is *transformed* by the rotation (which instead uses floating point), and after a certain rotation amount this shows some limits due to the floating point precision and integer conversion. I believe that you need a more complex implementation.

Comment: Is there a work around to make it work?

Comment: There's no "workaround", you need to implement the class in a different way: trying to "keep it simple" and using workarounds will only result in having another issue at some point of your further implementation. I suppose you still need this for your image selection/crop program, right?

Comment: Duly noted. Indeed, you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by various aspects:

- setting a QRect at given coordinates while keeping the item at the same default position (`0, 0`);
- changing the rectangle as consequence of a mouse move event;
- changing the transformation origin point after that;
- the mapping of the mouse coordinates between integer based point (on the screen) and floating (on the scene);
- the transformation (rotation);
- implementing the item movement without considering the above (while QGraphicsItem already provides it with the `ItemIsMovable` flag);

Note that while rotation might seem a simple operation, it is achieved by using a combination of two transformations: shearing and scaling; this means that the transformation applies very complex computations that depend on the floating point precision.
This becomes an issue when dealing with integer to floating conversion: the same mouse (integer based) coordinate can be mapped at a very different point depending on the transformation, and the "higher" the transformation is applied, the bigger the difference can be. As a result, the mapped mouse position can be very different, the rectangle is translated to a "wrong" point, and the transformation origin point moves the rectangle "away" by an increasing ratio.

The solution is to completely change the way the rectangle is positioned and actually simplify the reference: the rectangle is always *centered* at the item position, so that we can keep the transformation origin point at the default (`0, 0` in item coordinates).

The only inconvenience with this approach is that the item's `pos()` will not be on its top left corner anymore, but that is not a real issue: when the item is rotated, its top left corner would not be at that position anyway.

If you need to know the *actual* position of the item, you can then translate the rectangle based on the item scene position.
If you want to position the rectangle based on its top left corner, you have to map the position from the scene and compute the *delta* of the reference point (the *actual* top left corner).

I took the liberty of taking your previous question, which implemented the resizing, and improving it also to better show how the solution works.

```
class Selection(QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem):
    Left, Top, Right, Bottom = 1, 2, 4, 8
    def __init__(self, *args):
        rect = QtCore.QRectF(*args)
        pos = rect.center()
        # move the center of the rectangle to 0, 0
        rect.translate(-rect.center())
        super().__init__(rect)
        self.setPos(pos)
        self.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red, 5))
        self.setFlags(
            self.ItemIsMovable | 
            self.ItemIsSelectable | 
            self.ItemSendsGeometryChanges
        )

    def mapRect(self):
        return QtCore.QRectF(
            self.mapToScene(self.rect().topLeft()), 
            self.rect().size()
        )

    def setRectPosition(self, pos):
        localPos = self.mapFromScene(pos)
        delta = self.rect().topLeft() - localPos
        self.setPos(self.pos() + delta)

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change in (self.ItemPositionHasChanged, self.ItemRotationHasChanged):
            print(self.mapRect())
        return super().itemChange(change, value)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        pos = event.pos()
        rect = self.rect()
        margin = self.pen().width() / 2
        self.anchor = 0

        if pos.x() <= rect.x() + margin:
            self.anchor |= self.Left
        elif pos.x() >= rect.right() - margin:
            self.anchor |= self.Right

        if pos.y() <= rect.y() + margin:
            self.anchor |= self.Top
        elif pos.y() >= rect.bottom() - margin:
            self.anchor |= self.Bottom

        if self.anchor:
            self.clickAngle = QtCore.QLineF(QtCore.QPointF(), pos).angle()
        else:
            super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not self.anchor:
            super().mouseMoveEvent(event)
            return
        rect = self.rect()
        pos = event.pos()
        if self.anchor == self.Left:
            rect.setLeft(pos.x())
        elif self.anchor == self.Right:
            rect.setRight(pos.x())
        elif self.anchor == self.Top:
            rect.setTop(pos.y())
        elif self.anchor == self.Bottom:
            rect.setBottom(pos.y())
        else:
            # clicked on a corner, let's rotate
            angle = QtCore.QLineF(QtCore.QPointF(), pos).angle()
            rotation = max(0, min(90, self.rotation() + self.clickAngle - angle))
            self.setRotation(rotation)
            return
        pos = self.mapToScene(rect.center())
        self.setPos(pos)
        rect.moveCenter(QtCore.QPointF())
        self.setRect(rect)
```